# What's the most current reference for configuring Debian networking?

Tags: debian, networking

**What's the most current reference documentation for configuring Debian networking?**

---

I'm mired down in seeming old and outdated documentation.  Here's what I've found so far:

- [**Lots of man pages.**](https://manpages.debian.org/)  Some of them are new and some old, and because most are undated, it's hard to see what is what, in terms of age and what replaces what.

  Here is some of what I'm looking at (which I think are the most current):

  - **Layer 2 - links**
    **interfaces**(5) - configure physical and logical network interfaces, i.e. local hardware
    **ifup**(8)..  - run scripts to bring interfaces up or down
    **ip link(8)**  - other ways of bringing interfaces up or down
    **iw**(8)  - wireless network interfaces
    **networkctl**(1) - query the status of network links as seen by **systemd-networkd**
  - **Layer 3 - network**
    **hostname**(7) - set/get my hostname
    **hosts**(5) - mostly obsolete - seems now only to be used by browsers to browse local files
    **networks**(5) - define locally known network name, alias and ip addresses (obsolete?)
    **ip addr**(8)  - manage local IP addresses
    **networkmanager**(8), **nmcli**(1), **networkmanager.conf**(5), **nm-applet**(1), **nm-connection-editor**(1) - newer way to locally manage network??
    **minissdpd**(1) - daemon keeping track of UPnP devices up
    **inetd**(8) - daemon that listens on various TCP and UDP ports and spawns programs that can't or won't do it for themselves
    **nmap**(8) - Network exploration tool and security / port scanner
  - **Layer 4+ - transport or above**
    **ss**(8)  - manage sockets
    **ssh**(1) - remote login program
    **nfs**(5) fstab format and options for the nfs file systems
    ...
- [**The Debian Administrator's Handbook** -  chapter 8.2. Configuring the Network](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.network-config) - Undated, but it's now 2 major versions back, as Debian Buster is now up to version 10.  Debian 8, or Jessie was released in April 2015, so this is now **5 years old**.
- [**Debian Reference** - Chapter 5. Network setup](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_modern_network_configuration_without_gui) - but sadly says: "This chapter is getting outdated since this is based on Debian 7.0 (Wheezy) released in 2013.", so now **7 years old**.
- [**Linux Network Administrators Guide**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/) - 3rd edition (2005), now **15 years old!**

---

I'm hoping to better understand how the major network components fit together or replace each other on my system.

At the moment I'm trying to understand the ins and outs of using `NetworkManager`/`nmcli`, vs configuration files like `/etc/network/interfaces`, vs the `ifup/ifdown` and `ip`/`ss` commands, vs `systemd.network` (unit?) files.

I can see that `ip`, `ss`, and `iw` are the new command to learn, and am working on them.  But I can also see that `ifup` and `ifdown` are not going away, because they run scripts that `ip` does not.

And I'm still confused about how exactly my system gets it's ip from the dhcp on my router.

---

*(BTW, part of why I'm a little extra apprehensive about using old documentation.  I already wasted a bunch of time learning `iptables`, only to later find that they were old and that I should be learning `nftables`.)*

Thanks!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most current reference for configuring Debian networking is [the corresponding chapter of the Debian Reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html), in spite of the warning you mention. The information contained there is still relevant for Debian 10.

You’ll also need to refer to various other documents, mentioned in the Debian Reference; for example, `/usr/share/doc/network-manager/README.Debian` if you’re using Network Manager, or the systemd documentation if you’re using systemd-networkd, or the manpages for `ifup`, `interfaces`, and the various iproute2 tools if you’re using `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Your system gets its IP address in the DHCP information it receives from your gateway.